# How can I click a button in VB and highlight a text box and copies conent to clipboard?

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox, onclick

This question is about having a button and text box. And when you click the button, the text in the text box highlights and is copied to your clipboard it one quick move. I'm building this code in VB (Microsoft, Visual Basic 2010).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       [...]
End Sub
```

Awaiting the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Clipboard.SetText(Me.TextBox1.Text, TextDataFormat.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped you, now you can set the question as answered.