# How to add a "Copy Button" to SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

The users of my SSRS report always select the entire text in the report, then right-click and copy it (then they paste it elsewhere). So, it would be of great benefit if I could add a copy button that would simply copy the entire content of the report - ready for pasting. So they can just click the button, and go elsewhere and simply paste it. Is this possible in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  It is possible to copy all text from a textbox but there are no viable options to only copy selected text to clipboard.

[How can I click a button in VB and highlight a text box and copies conent to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117087/how-can-i-click-a-button-in-vb-and-highlight-a-text-box-and-copies-conent-to-cli)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: That is the answer. They asked is it possible and my answer is no.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw the link you submitted, but that only works in C# or Visual Basic.. How would this be possible in SSRS? Sorry I'm not a pro, I just don't see a way of implementing that referenced solution into SSRS

Comment: you right click outside the report and you select report properties. Then go to the code tab and you can enter custom vb code. Then when you want to use it create an expression and use Code.(whatever your function name is)